# Concavification of Orlicz function

Tags: banach-spaces, orlicz-spaces

In the Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, vol 1, page 855, Johnson and Schechtman say that if $M$ is an Orlicz function, the following are equivalent:

- The unit vector basis of the Orlicz space $\ell_M$ is $p$-convex and $2$-concave;
- $M(\left|t\right|^\frac{1}{p})$ is equivalent to a convex function and $M(t^{\frac{1}{2}})$ is equivalent to a concave function on $[0, \infty)$

And they give as reference *Application de l'étude de certaines formes linéaires aléatoires au plongement d'espaces de Banach dans des espaces $L^p$*, by J. Bretagnolle and D. Dacunha-Castelle, which I cannot understand since I don't speak French.

So my question is: how does one prove this result?

Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind including, what an Orlicz-function is? (I could think of different meanings…)

Comment: An Orlicz function $M : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an even convex function such that $M(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} M(t) = \infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that $M(t) \geq 0$ for every $t$.